# is a free group a discrete group?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Can I say that free groups are discrete groups? My question arises from the fact that free groups act on trees, and trees are graphs that can be viewed as a topological space (the graph topology).

Comment: I have no answer, but you make me a bit curious: what exactly is a discrete group? Fact is that discrete topologies function as topologies that are free over a set. So in that sense there is link between free and discrete.

Comment: From definition, a discrete group is a group G equipped with the discrete topology.

Comment: Thank you. I have read the answer of Daniel and understand that it handles about topological groups. I know what they are, but never worked with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group has no topological structure *apriori*, and every group can be given a topological structure as a discrete group. Groups can also be given other topological structures, and further some of these topological structures will make the group into a topological group (the relevant functions will be continuous given these topological structures). The discrete topology on a group always makes it into a topological group (as every function from a discrete space is continuous, and the product of two discrete spaces is discrete).

Comment: @MiguelC. I should mention that a group action on a topological space can also be discrete. Probably the most concise definition of which is that if $\rho\colon G\times X\to X$ is a continuous $G$-action on $X$, then $\rho$ is a discrete group action if $\{\rho_g\colon X\to X\colon x\mapsto \rho(g,x)\mid g\in G\}$ is a discrete subgroup of the automorphism group of $X$ given the compact open topology. This may be the notion you were thinking of.

Comment: This information is very helpful. Thanks very much.

Comment: I think we must add an important piece of info here: We **indeed** can consider free groups (and, in fact, *any* other group) as a topological group with the discrete topology **because** any function from a discrete space to *any* topological space is continuous. Without this it could be possible the group's operation is *not* continuous in the given topology and thus the group cannot be a topological group.

Comment: @DonAntonio Agreed, I've added another short sentence to the answer to reinforce this.